# Recurrence of an MSIEXEC package deployment through GPO

Tags: group-policy, installation, deployment, msi

We want to use this simple command in a batch file:
msiexec /package "\path\package.msi" /quiet /norestart

We want to deploy it to all users and their machines.
We want it to be installed only once, and we suspect that if we keep only this command inside the batch script (and not add some IFs and ELSEs) then some unexpected things might happen, such as recurring of installations each time a user logs on etc.

What will practically happen if we keep just this command in the script, and a user who already has this package installed logs on, and the script executes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's an MSI, you're better off using Group Policy Software Deployment rather than a batch. It does *exactly* what you're looking for without having to test for previous installs.

As for your actual question:

> What will practically happen if we keep just this command in the script, and a user who already has this package installed logs on, and the script executes?

If you don't test for the installation in your script, it will keep reinstalling.